# Question about the decimal display in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am currently having a matrix generated by numpy as the following"

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [-9.9999998  27.99999907  0.        ]
 [ 9.99999992 -0.99999964  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -2.66666665]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          1.        ]
 [ 0.         -0.99999992  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

May I know how shall I display all the 0 in the form of 0.00000000 (8 decimal places)?

Comment: did my answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.set_printoptions`. Using this you can change the default way of printing a numpy object.

There are several options, but you need to understand just two: `precision` and `floatmode`. The first one is:

> Number of digits of precision for floating point output (default 8).

And the second one:

> Controls the interpretation of the precision option for floating-point types.

Since you want `precision = 8` you don't need to change it because it is the default value. Therefore, all you need to do is (assuming you imported numpy as `np`):

```
np.set_printoptions(floatmode = "maxprec_equal")
```

And then print your matrix. It does exactly what you want.

You can read more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).